# Instance metadata on IBM Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, ibm-cloud, metadata

Is there any way to get instance metadata on IBM Cloud Kubernetes cluster, from internal pod? Something like doing `curl` to `http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/...` on GKE clusters, or `http://169.254.169.254/latest/...` on EKS clusters.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I follow what you're after.. you're able to get details/metadata about your worker node from the SoftLayer APIs available - https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/softlayerapi/

For k8s specific info you can utilize the k8s api-server to query metadata about things like the node, pods, etc at the `Kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local` address from inside a pod. You can find the service account and token from within your pod at `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io`

Hope that helps.